# Sed Replace Outside Substrings around Inner Substring

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am attempting to replace contents sitting between an opening string and an ending string, such as the following, where the bolded text is what is being replaced.

**beginningSubstring** sometext **endingSubstring**

I want to turn this into something else, such as the following.

**newString** sometext **newString**

How would I go about making this replacement with a single sed (or awk)?

---

My specific use case is I am using curl on a website to retrieve info at the Linux CLI, and I am attempting to display various content. I want to make the output more readable/shorter and would like to replace HTML tags such as `<strong>someText</strong>` with `*someText*` or `<em>someText</em>` with `~someText~` in order to maintain the existence of the content without completely removing it. I would like a single sed to make this replacement as I want to keep the opening and closing tags paired together, so that I don't have to determine whether or not there is the existence of a previously replaced opening tag in order to determine what the closing tag should be.

Comment: don't parse HTML with non syntax aware parser like `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `sed`

```
$ echo "<strong>someText</strong> <p>XXX</p>  <strong>someOtherText</strong>"
  sed -E 's_<strong>([^<]*)</strong>_*\1*_g'
```

will give

```
*someText* <p>XXX</p>  *someOtherText*
```

however, not recommend for html and special chars which you need to provision for.  Perhaps you're looking for html to markdown translator.

Comment: The replacement did effectively work, but I believe a program such as html2text or another html to markdown converter might be a better, more efficient step, as I am having to use multiple sed commands in this particular use case.
I was still interested in how to replace the surrounding strings.